# Optimized detection of which regex in a list matches an input

Tags: regex, parsing, optimization, computer-science, lexical-analysis

Suppose I have a list of regexes, like so:

1. `File ".*" not found`
2. `Out of memory`
3. `You do not have permission to perform this action`
4. `Network connection to [^ ]* failed`
5. `Unrecognized command: .*`
6. ....

(In practice, the list will be maybe 100 items long for my use case, and will periodically have items added to it.)

Given an input, I want to quickly (say, minimal worst-case runtime, although I'm open to other measures of "quickly," as well as approximate guarantees thereof) determine which of the above, if any, my input matches.  (If there are multiple matches, let's say we can return the index of *any* match.  Or, if it helps, we can also require that the regexes on the initial list be mutually exclusive.)

So for instance if I don't care about performance I could just write something like this (pseudocode):

```
for(int i = 0; i < expressions.length; i++)
{
  if(expressions[i].matches(input) { return i; }
}

return NO_MATCH;
```

However, for the list above, one could write something considerably more efficient, e.g.

```
switch(input[0])
{
  case 'F':
    return expression[0].match(input) ? 0 : NO_MATCH;

  case 'O':
    return expression[1].match(input) ? 1 : NO_MATCH;

  // ...
}
```

Of course, depending on the nature of the items in the list, switching on the first character might not be the way to go.  I would like something that takes as input a list of regexes as above and outputs an optimized algorithm for determining which item, if any, matches.

This seems similar to a number of commonly dealt-with problems, such as:

- lexer and parser generation
- regex tries
- building a state machine to recognize a regular language

However, at least as far as I can tell (and maybe I'm missing something), there's no straightforward way to use tools designed for the above to get what I want here.

Comment: You'll get that feature automatically if you use a lexer generator such as lex, flex or re2c which compiles a list of regexes into a state machine. There are regex libraries which produce efficiently compiled matcherd -- Russ Cox's `re2` springs to mind -- but you also need the ability to work with a list of alternatives and identify which one matched, which seems to be much less common in regex libraries.

Comment: If your problem is that you can't figure out how to use, say, flex or re2c to solve your *concrete* problem, you'll need to explain why not, because it's usually pretty simple. But it's hard to provide a concrete answer to a question without specifics.

Comment: @rici My understanding was that lex/flex doesn't do much in the way of optimization beyond splitting stuff up by the first couple of letters, but to be fair it's also been roughly 20 years since I last did something with lex.  I will give it a shot and see what it does.

Comment: That's never been the way (f)lex works. From the beginning, it compiled the set of patterns into a single state machine, which means that pattern match time is linear in the length of the text matched.